# OPenWRT Load balance 2 DSL routers using a 3rd(4 LAN, 1 WAN port router)?

Tags: routing, openwrt

I would like to install open-WRT on a router MR3420  v 2.3 and want to know if it can act as Load balancer for 2 DSL routers below. but I am not sure if openWRT will solve the following use-case
I have two DSL connections providing internet

1. Unreliable - 4MB (Router has 4 LAN and 1 WAN ports )
2. Reliable but only 2MB (This router has only 2 LAN ports available)

And an extra 3rd router (4 LANS , 1 WAN,  MR3420 v 2.3) on which I want to install openwrt and use it as a load balancing router for the above DSL routers so that I can smoothly browse internet without switching WiFi frequently.

Question: 
MR3420  has only one WAN port and my assumption is it should have 2 WAN ports to support the two DSL connections above? am I right ? or Can I plug the cables from the DSL routers into the LAN ports of the 3rd router and yet use it as Load balancing router using openWRT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this, if the router supports VLAN, then it is possible to convert LAN ports to WAN ports in openWrt,

```
       Networks -> Switch 
       Enable VLAN 
       Then tag the ports
```

so the router can connect to multiple WAN interfaces even if it does not have enough WAN ports.